# NSInvalidArgumentException: unrecognized selector sent to instance | SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I realize this question has been asked many times, but it seems to be caused by many different things and is very situational.

My trace:

```
2015-02-27 16:20:06.289 RTApp[43486:1122681] -[RTApp.conversationVC keyboardWasShown]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f866a766830
2015-02-27 16:20:06.291 RTApp[43486:1122681] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RTApp.conversationVC keyboardWasShown]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f866a766830'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001071b8f35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000106e51bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001071c004d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010711827c ___forwarding___ + 988
4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107117e18 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107188cec __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
6   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001070888a4 _CFXNotificationPost + 2484
7   Foundation                          0x00000001069af6b8 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
8   UIKit                               0x0000000107c75eb8 -[UIInputWindowController postEndNotifications:withInfo:] + 527
9   UIKit                               0x0000000107c77725 __77-[UIInputWindowController moveFromPlacement:toPlacement:starting:completion:]_block_invoke572 + 354
10  UIKit                               0x0000000107617113 -[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:] + 326
11  UIKit                               0x00000001075fee6a -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 209
12  UIKit                               0x00000001075ff1a0 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 76
13  QuartzCore                          0x0000000105c4c7ee _ZN2CA5Layer23run_animation_callbacksEPv + 308
14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108de57f4 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108dce8fb _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 949
16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107120fe9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
17  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001070e3eeb __CFRunLoopRun + 2043
18  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001070e3486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
19  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010aa0f9f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
20  UIKit                               0x00000001075a5420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
21  RTApp                               0x000000010563623e top_level_code + 78
22  RTApp                               0x000000010563627a main + 42
23  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000108e1a145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

And the function in question:

```
func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification){

    let dict:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
    let s:NSValue = dict.valueForKey(UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey) as NSValue
    let rect:CGRect = s.CGRectValue()

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0, options: .CurveLinear, animations: {
        self.resultsScrollView.frame.origin.y = self.scrollViewOriginalY - rect.height
        self.frameMessageView.frame.origin.y = self.frameMessageOriginalY - rect.height

        var bottomOffset:CGPoint = CGPointMake(0, self.resultsScrollView.contentSize.height - self.resultsScrollView.bounds.size.height)
        self.resultsScrollView.setContentOffset(bottomOffset, animated: false)

        }, completion: {
            (finished:Bool) in
    })
}
```

So this should just be pushing the view up so it's not covered by the keyboard as you type. But as soon as I pull the keyboard up, it crashes. It would be great if Xcode told you what line the error is on, but that would be too easy..

Does this mean the function doesn't recognizer the parameter I'm passing in to it? Or why can't it recognize the 'selector'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging by the error message `reason: '-[RTApp.conversationVC keyboardWasShown]: unrecognized selector` you used the wrong selector when you added the Notification Observer.

You should use `Selector("keyboardWasShown:")` instead of `Selector("keyboardWasShown")` because your method has one parameter.

Comment: thanks. and also, thanks for not being rude cause I've been looking through other questions, and let me tell you the objective-c/swift community is wayy harsher than the ruby community.